# How can Eclipse find the jar in the editor but not when it's time to compile?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, classpath, war

I am trying to build a dynamic web project - if I add the Tomcat as a dependency, it does compile just fine. However, I have run into a peculiar situation that doesn't resolve properly.

Obviously I have many references to `servlet-api.jar` in my code for things like `HttpServlet`. Eclipse complains that it can't find `HttpServlet` and yet when I ctrl+click `HttpServlet` it recognizes that it lives in `c:\programs\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar` - how can it know that it's there during editing and yet not during build/compile/export?

Comment: This needs more details, like version numbers and fully qualified type names to start.

Comment: Oh wow, look at that. Eclipse seemed to find a `servlet-api.jar` that has a `jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet` while trying to find what I was looking for which is `javax.servlet.HttpServlet`. I guess I need to just dive into which libraries were included in the two different Tomcat libs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl+Click works by different rules. Because of the way the type indexing works, it doesn't attempt to fully qualify the type you're hovering over if the reference is not already fully qualified, so it will still match types of the same name in different packages. It's faster, and *usually* doesn't cause confusion.